# get a better protection of my email password in Django

Tags: python, django, email

I have a form on my website and once it is submitted, it sends an email to mail own mailbox.

My problem is that, to do so, I hardcoded my email and my password in my settings.py like this:

```
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myemail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypassword'
```

but I feel that it is not secured at all, so I try to find a way to make it not hardcoded in my settings.py. Based on how I store my secret key, I tried the following thing:

```
with open('/Users/myapp/email.txt') as f:
    EMAIL_HOST_USER = f.read().strip()

with open('/Users/myapp/email_password.txt') as f:
    EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = f.read().strip()
```

But it did not work. It raises an SMTP error: "Username and Password not accepted."

Any idea on how to protect my password better ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an environment variable, and then read it in your settings like:

```
import os
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environment.get('EMAIL_HOST_USER')
```

Then you can keep the value out of your repo.

The environment needs need to be in effect for the process that is running Django.

Comment: Great it seems to work ! Do you think it is more secured than reading it from a txt file ? so that I also use this technique to store my secret key